# Disablic spell check while keeping autocorrect in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

In my UITextView when a user spells something incorrectly, it gets underlined in red. How can I remove this without disabling autocorrect?

Answer (score 3):

Text views have properties for both autocorrection and spelling checking. These can be set in the Attributes inspector. Or in code via `spellCheckingType` and `autocorrectionType`. In your case you would want to disable spell checking whilst leaving autocorrect enabled.

The various possible constant values are detailed at: [UITextInputTraits](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/#//apple_ref/swift/enum/UITextSpellCheckingType)

Answer (score -1):

You can call this function where ever you wanted to check the spelling THen use bellow code

```
     func wordIsSpelledCorrect(_ word: String) -> Bool {
    let checker = UITextChecker()
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, word.characters.count)
    let wordRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: word, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en")
    return wordRange.location == NSNotFound



}
```

Use in this way

```
        if wordIsSpelledCorrect((yourTextField.text)!){
```

}